# Compile Multiple Versions of C Program for Testing

Tags: git, makefile, c99

I want to write some integration tests that test the interaction between two versions of my code. Essentially I'd like to test that the current commit can communicate with its parent commit. So I need to compile two different commits in a Makefile. Is there a recommended way to do this for C code? My first idea is to compile the current branch, and then use a git checkout command to checkout the previous branch and compile again. I feel a little weird about using git commands in a Makefile though, so any advice on this would be helpful.

Comment: This is not a job for Git itself, and perhaps not a job for Make as it's really a kind of acceptance test. In that kind of test system, you'd have, or create, the two builds to be tested against each other, and then run whatever tests are appropriate. This might *use* Git and Make to obtain the versions and build them, but it's logically separate from those steps. It might also use Make to run the test setup, but again, that's separate from using Make to build the program.

Comment: Side note: the overall test harness might use `git worktree add` to extract the two versions to be tested against each other, since that makes it easy to build each one. (It also makes it easy to debug the pair if they *don't* work together.)